# Sorting a Ruby array of hashes based on the amount of times a value appears

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have an array of hashes as follows:

```rb
details = [
  {:name => "Alice", :age => 20},
  {:name => "Ted",   :age => 25},
  {:name => "Poppy", :age => 33},
  {:name => "Amy",   :age => 20},
  {:name => "Ted",   :age => 90},
  {:name => "Amy",   :age => 22},
  {:name => "Ted",   :age => 23}
]
```

I want to be able to sort so that I can order based on how many times the names of each person appear. For example, output might be:
`"Ted, Ted, Ted, Amy, Amy, Alice, Poppy"`

Can anyone please help? :)

Thanks

Comment: Did you tried something by yourself?

Comment: If you only want the names, it might be easier to extract them via `details.map { |h| h[:name] }` and then sort `["Alice", "Ted", "Poppy", "Amy", "Ted", "Amy", "Ted"]` by the number of occurrences. It's basically the same task but working with simpler objects (strings instead of hashes containing those strings) makes it easier to grasp.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get a name-counting hash, then sort by the name counts:

```
details.each.with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |e, c| c[e[:name]] += 1 }.
    then { |c| details.sort_by { |e| -c[e[:name]] } }.
    map { |e| e[:name] }
```

Comment: ...or `c[e[:name]] -= 1` with `{ |e| c[e[:name]] }`. For readers unfamiliar with [Object#then](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Object.html#method-i-then), it made its debut in v2.6.

Answer (score 0):

this will return based on the name attribute occurrence:

```
sorted_group_details = details.group_by{|d| d[:name]}.sort_by{|key, val| val.count}
```

by default, it returns ascending order. if you want to order by the most occurrence just add `reverse`

```
sorted_group_details.reverse
```

and, if you want to return a flatten object from the grouped array:

```
sorted_group_details.map{|d| d[1]}.flatten
```

Answer (score 0):

```
output_array = []
Hash[details.group_by{|data| data[:name]}.transform_values(&:count).sort_by{|k,v| v}.reverse].each{|key,value| value.times do output_array.push(key)  end }
```

output_array will have the results

Answer (score 0):

```
details.map { |h| h[:name] }.
        group_by(&:itself).
        values.
        sort_by { |a| -a.size }.
        flatten
  #=> ["Ted", "Ted", "Ted", "Amy", "Amy", "Alice", "Poppy"]
```

One can tack on `.join(', ')` if a string is desired instead:

```
"Ted, Ted, Ted, Amy, Amy, Alice, Poppy"
```

The most expensive operation here is sorting, which is O(n*log(n)); all other operations are O(n). Let

```
arr = ["Alice", "Ted", "Poppy", "Amy", "Ted", "Amy", "Ted"]
```

By executing `group_by` and `values` before `sort_by`, only

```
n = arr.uniq.size 
  #=> 4
```

values need be sorted, as opposed to sorting all 7 elements `arr`.

The steps are as follows.

```
b = details.map { |h| h[:name] }
  #=> ["Alice", "Ted", "Poppy", "Amy", "Ted", "Amy", "Ted"] 
c = b.group_by(&:itself)
  #=> {"Alice"=>["Alice"], "Ted"=>["Ted", "Ted", "Ted"], "Poppy"=>["Poppy"],
  #    "Amy"=>["Amy", "Amy"]} 
d = c.values
  #=> [["Alice"], ["Ted", "Ted", "Ted"], ["Poppy"], ["Amy", "Amy"]] 
e = d.sort_by { |a| -a.size }
  #=> [["Ted", "Ted", "Ted"], ["Amy", "Amy"], ["Alice"], ["Poppy"]] 
e.flatten
  #=> ["Ted", "Ted", "Ted", "Amy", "Amy", "Alice", "Poppy"]
```